# How do i pull users from a team in Microsoft Bot Framework on Microsoft Teams on app install

Tags: rest, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm having trouble proactively sending messages. I have a bot successfully sent up and I hear all messages sent to me and can respond. I'm unable to get any event when the app is installed. I've been installing the app using the embedded code link that looks like https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=**:***************************. All I want is some event send to me on installation so I can then pull all user ids for the team that installed the app. I am trying to use the REST api since I am working in laravel.

Comment: Could you please try proactive-message sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages).

Comment: The link you've posted is for a chat - how are you installing the app (bot) into an actual team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you mentioned is the deep link that is used to navigate to your bot on click on the link where you can chat with it.

You can use the Manifest file to install the app.

You can use the app setup policy to install your bot to all the users in the organization :-[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies).

or you can use Microsoft Graph API which is in beta version to install an all to the users:- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-add-teamsappinstallation?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Once the bot is installed to the user, the Conversation Update event will be triggered, where you can capture and store the User's Teams Unique ID which you can use to send Proactive messages.

you can also refer to this [Link](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3191).

Thanks.

Comment: I took I break from this because I was getting to frustrated. Where is the manifest file? I see documentation on it but I have no idea where to edit it. I checked my Bot Channel Registration, my Resource Group, my App Service, and my App Service Plan